# How to add a border to a clipped image?

Tags: flutter, clip-path

I am able to clip the image with ClipPath but how can I add a border to that clipped image as following?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can Solve it this way :

1. create a `CustomPainter` with the same `Path` in the `CustomClipper<Path>`

> Example :

```
Path path = Path();
path.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.8);
path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
path.close();
```

2. create a `Paint` Object and with Stroke painting Style and the `strokeWidth` is the width of your custom border

> CODE

```
Paint paint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth=10.0
  ..color = Colors.black;
```

and finally draw this path in `canvas`

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

also you need to make sure that this `CustomPaint` is the child of your container

```
ClipPath(
          clipper: traingleclipper(),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: ClipperBorderPainter(),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

in my Example this is the result :

[image]

also there is another way using a `Stack` in this way you will create the image with clipper and then create the `CustomPaint` with the same `Path`

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
              clipper: CustomClip(),
                child: Image.network(
              "http://www.delonghi.com/Global/recipes/multifry/pizza_fresca.jpg",
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 400.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
            CustomPaint(
              painter: BorderPainter(),
              child: Container(
                height: 400.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]
[Full Example](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/a049f0611f366024d4c39b5a68d561c0)